# How to play Audio only in a video file in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Is there any way to play audio only in `AVPlayer`Even though the url stream has both Audio and video?

Comment: AVPlayer has use to play video file and if you have both then its play both audio and video if you want to stop to play video then its better to use avaudioplayer for play only audio

Comment: I want to switch to audio while the player is playing the video. If I create AVAudioPlayer won't it start to play from the begining. I want to swith between audio and video smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your video player size 0x0 or place it outside of the screen.

Comment: If I did like that will it still consume the bandwidth it requires to play both video and video?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. You cannot extract only the audio track from the stream on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

You can. I have verified with a local mp4 video. You have to disable the video tracks after the `AVPlayerItem` loads them.

The simplest implementation looks like this.

```
let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
var token: NSKeyValueObservation!
token = item.observe(\.tracks) { item, _ in
    item.tracks
        .filter { $0.assetTrack?.mediaType == .video }
        .forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }
    token.invalidate()
}
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
player.play()
```

Alternatively, you can add a dummy video output. This still consumes resources, however.

```
let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
item.add(AVPlayerItemVideoOutput())
let player = AVPlayer(url: item)
```

Comment: I've tested this proposed solution using HLS streams and it's not working.